# I'm having trouble finding the right direction to take in this HIV modeling exercise

Tags: mathematical-modeling

Cells that are susceptible to HIV infection are called T (target) cells. Let $T(t)$ be the population of uninfected T-cells, $T*(t)$ that of the infected T-cells, and $V(t)$ the population of the HIV virus. A model for the rate of change of the infected T-cells is

$$\frac{dT^{ * }}{dt}=kVT-\delta T^{ * },  \quad (1)$$

where $\delta$ is the rate of clearance of infected cells by the body, and $k$ is the rate constant for the infection of the T-cells by the virus. The equation for the virus is the same as above:

$$\frac{dV}{dt}=P-cV,  (2)$$

but now the production of the virus can be modeled by $P(t)=N\delta T^{ * }(t)$. Here $N$ is the total number of virions produced by an infected T-cell during its lifetime. Since  $\frac{1}{\delta}$ is the length of its lifetime, $N\delta T^{ * }(t)$ is the total rate of production of $V(t)$.

At least during the initial stages of infection, $T$ can be treated as an approximate constant. Equations (1) and (2) are the two coupled equations for the two variables $T*(t)$ and $V(t)$.

A drug therapy using RT inhibitors blocks infection, leading to $k\cong 0$. Setting $k=0$ in (1), solve for $T*(t)$. Substitute it into (2) and solve for $V(t)$. Show the solution is $V(t)=\frac{V(0)}{c-\delta}[ce^{-\delta t}-\delta e^{-ct}]$.

Answer (score 1):

I think the last paragraph of yours already gave you the direction. Set $k=0$ in (1), you will get

$$\frac{dT^{ * }}{dt}=-\delta T^{ * }$$

This can be solved by separation of variables. Plugging this solution into the second equation, you will get a linear differential equation. I'm sure you've learned how to solve these in differential equations.

Edit:

$$\frac{dV}{dt}=N\delta T^*(0)e^{-\delta t}-cV\\
\frac{dV}{dt}+cV=N\delta T^*(0)e^{-\delta t}$$

is a linear equation. You should multiply by $e^{ct}$ on both sides:

$$e^{ct}\frac{dV}{dt}+cVe^{ct}=N\delta T^*(0)e^{ct-\delta t}$$

which becomes

$$(e^{ct}V)'=N\delta T^*(0)e^{ct-\delta t}$$

Now can you integrate both sides and continue?

Comment: I can get to that part, but after that I'm not too sure how to go about it. Don't know what to do after I plug it back in

Comment: If you can show your work, I will point out what to do next.

Comment: dT*/dt=-\delta T* this implies that T*(t)=T*(0)e^(-\delta t) because its an exponential decay this implies P(t)=N\delta T*(0)e^(-\delta t). Then plugging it back into equation 2 I get dV/dt=N\delta T*(0)e^(-\delta t)-cV. The equation doesn't make sense

Comment: I edited the answer.